# Python: iterating through a dict in the order in which items were inserted

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

```
d = { 'c' : 1, 'f': 2, 'a': 3}

for key, value in d.iteritems():
    print key
```

I want to be able to iterate through the keys in the order in which they were inserted.

I've looked at converting dict to OrderedDict but they seemed to be have some sort of order (not the order of their insertion)

Is there a easy way to convert dict to OrderedDict which maintains the order of insertion?

Comment: By the time you create a dict, you have lost the order.  If you want the order, you need to create an OrderedDict right from the start.

Comment: @BrenBarn alright thats what i thought but just checking with the smart ppl on here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't convert your `dict` to an `OrderedDict`, you should be using an `OrderedDict` in the first place:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()
od['c'] = 1
od['f'] = 2
od['a'] = 3
```

Or often easier, create the `OrderedDict` from a `list` of tuples or a `tuple` of `tuples`:

```
od = OrderedDict([('c', 1), ('f', 2), ('a', 3)])
```

The problem with converting a `dict` to an `OrderedDict` is that as soon as you create a `dict` or add anything into it, the order is lost. So you can't use a `dict` at all if you need to keep the order.